# how can set reverse zone in free dns providers as in bind9 etc.?

Tags: dns, bind, reverse-dns

because of some complicated issue, I decide use freedns.centos-webpanel.com to manage my dns.

as I know and used bind9, you can create in-addr.arpa files to handle reverse zone and avoid spam for mail server. but in freedns of cwp there is no item for that.

used this but not answered in result of dig -x:

```
@ PTR example.com
```

I'm afraid of making my own dns server because of ddos and dns attacks. what's best free solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudflare to manage your DNS. I found it as more secure as I am using it since many years. If you want to manage your own DNS, you need to disable ping to your DNS server to avoid yourself from minimum attacks. CWP is basically web hosting panel which is included with DNS management like any other web hosting panels.